# Links between "Interaction Information" and interactions in a linear regression model.

Tags: regression, interaction, mutual-information

I'm trying to get a handle on interactions between three variables in a regression-sense and how they differ from interactions in an information theory sense.

Imagine we wish to determine whether two factors X and Z are interacting in the context of Y.

For the mutual information based-measure, we use [interaction information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_information), expressed as
\begin{aligned}
I(X; Z; Y) &= I(X; Z|Y)+I(X; Y) \\
           &= I(X, Z; Y) - [ I(X; Y)+I(Z; Y)]
\end{aligned}
where I is mutual information. Here, the interaction information can be interpreted the information expressed by X and Z together in the context of Y
minus the information by X and Z separately in the context of Y.

The more common approach is to use a [regression based approach](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interaction_%28statistics%29). Here, we compare a linear model with terms for X and Z and their interaction (denoted here as interaction model)

$$
Y=\beta_1X+\beta_2Z+\beta_3XZ 
$$
to a model with only the X and Z factors as individual terms (denote as additive model)
$$
Y=\beta_1X+\beta_2 Z
$$
To test for interaction, we may use a likelihood ratio test to determine whether
the likelihood of the interaction model is better than that of the additive model. That is, whether Y can be modelled better if we examine the interaction of X and Z as opposed to just modelling the additive effects of X and Y.

Is there any link between these two approaches to quantifying interaction? Are they defining interaction in a similar way? To my eyes they appear to be based on two very different underlying intuitions about what constitutes an interaction. Given that the wikipedia page on interactions is pretty clear that interactions are typically defined as deviation from additivity, I'm curious to know whether interaction information can be fit into that framework.